# Box shadow of one div onto another

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ye7cndxz/)

```
    <div id="headDiv">
        <h1 id="headh1">Welcome</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="container">

    </div>
```

I want shadow of welcome div on container div. so that it'll look like it is placed above container div.
Right now as you can see shadow is on body but bot on container div.

help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/ye7cndxz/3/

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative;` to your `#headDiv` in CSS.

Tried it and it works...

Answer (score 1):

You've done almost everything what is needed, to be done. You forgot about position and [z-index](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/).

Adding `position:relative` and `z-index:99999` will give you what you need.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #faf6eb;
}
#headDiv {
  width: 90%;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
  background-color: #354458;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
}
#headh1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #E6E6E6;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
}
#container {
  width: 88%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  background: #9DC0CB;
  margin-top: -10px;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="headDiv">
  <h1 id="headh1">Welcome</h1>
</div>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: z-index is not required here. Also for reference your z index value is unrealistic and bad practise. Please use a better value in future.

Comment: @jbutler483 values are only to illustrate the example. From my points of view z-index is required if you have a complex website.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe you are mistaken. Z-index is not required here, and I would severely suggest to use realistic z-values *if* I was going to use them. In this case, however, they are not required at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the other solutions is that in the original layout, container hides part of the head, so if you put head above the container (which is required to get the shadow) you will ruin the previous effect.

Instead, fake the shadow on the container itself with

```
.container {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 7px -7px blue; 
}
```

```css
body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color:#faf6eb; 
}
#headDiv{
 width:90%;
 height:130px;
 margin-top:0px;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
 background-color: #354458;
 margin: 0 auto;
 vertical-align: middle;  
}

#headh1{
 font-size: 3em;
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 30px; 
 color: #E6E6E6;
 text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
}

#container{
 width:88%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 300px;
 background: #9DC0CB; 
 margin-top: -10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 7px -7px blue; 
}
```

```html
<div id="headDiv">
   <h1 id="headh1">Welcome</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div id="container">
   
  </div>
```